# how to log all the inbound and outbound connections of an android device programmatically with android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming

i am new to android development, how to log all the inbound and outbound connections of an android device with android studio, i would take the inbound and outbound logs and do other operations on it. the logs can be written to a file or simply show on a list. Any GitHub project with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

option 1)If you have a rooted device ,you may opt to use
android-pcap from here https://github.com/enukane/android-pcap
 option 2) if you don't plan on using on rooted devices,you can root your network traffic to a pc or server via wifi tethering or VPN then do the packet processing there which easier using the NPCAP from here https://nmap.org/npcap/ and send back processed data to the android device either via a HTTP request or tcp connection